# Combinatorics Sequence and Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Given $n$ is odd,number of ways in which $3$ numbers in AP can be selected from $1,2,3,4, \ldots, n$ is?
(I tried with some examples and I'm getting something like $$\frac{(n-1)^2}{4}$$ but not getting a direct combinatorial or algebraic technique.Please Help.)

Comment: For clarification, you are asking in how many ways you can pick three numbers: $x_1=a, x_2=a+b, x_3=a+2b$ from the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$?  (I.e. $x_1,x_2,x_3$ form an arithmetic progression?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If common difference is d. 
Then for $d=1$ we have $n-1*(3-1)=n-2$, 
$\qquad$ for $d=2$ we have $n-2*(3-1)=n-4$,
$\qquad$ for $d=3$ we have $n-3*(3-1)=n-6$,
And so on...
You can sum these?

Comment: You beat me to it, but my answer agrees.  Noting that for $d\geq \frac{n}{2}$ there are zero ways (instead of accidentally continuing to sum "negative" numbers of ways).

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks

Comment: nice solution!well the last term is 1.

Comment: (n-2)+(n-4)+...+1=(n-1)^2/4

Answer (score 1):

To find an arithmetic progression we must select $3$ numbers such that :
$$x+y=2z$$

but this is equivalent two selecting two different integers ($x$ and $y$, the third $z$ will be half $x+y$) with the same parity hence :
$$\dbinom{2}{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}+\dbinom{2}{\left\lfloor\frac {n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}$$

Comment: try `\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor`

Answer (score 0):

For $n=2m+1,$

**Case** $\#1:$ If the first term, common difference be $2r+1,d$ respectively

Clearly, $d>0$

we need $2r+1+2d\le2m+1\iff r+d\le m$

So, $0\le r\le m-1\implies m$ possible values

**Case** $\#2:$ If the first term, common difference be $2r,d$ respectively

we need $2r+2d\le2m+1\iff r+d\le m$

Now $1\le r\le m-1\implies m-1$ possible values