# Number of ways in which 3 numbers in Arithmetic progression can be selected from 1,2,3....n is?

Tags: combinatorics

Initially i thought of dividing the sequence into groups of 3 that is 1,2,3,4,.. gets divided in to consecutive groups which means there are a total of $n\over 3$ groups and hence the total was of selecting is $${n\over 3}\choose{1}$$

but the answer is given to be ${n(n-2)}\over 4$ if n is even and ${(n-1)^2}\over 4$ if n is odd
a similar problem was asked in [Combinatorics Sequence and Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188488/combinatorics-sequence-and-series) but i did not understand the method

Answer (score 3):

If $n=2k$ the number of $3$-term arithmetic progressions in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$
is
$$0+1+2+3+\cdots+(k-1)+(k-1)+\cdots+3+2+1+0=k(k-1)$$
because, for $1\le i\le k$, the number of such progressions centered at $i$ is $i-1$.
Similarly, if $n=2k+1$, the number is
$$0+1+2+3+\cdots+(k-1)+k+(k-1)+\cdots+3+2+1+0=k(k-1)+k=k^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ be in A.P.

Then $2b= a+c$; => $a$ and $c$ both are odd **OR** both are even.

*Case 1*. when $n$ is even.

No. of ways of selecting two even numbers = $\binom {n/2}{2}$.

And no. of ways of selecting two odd numbers = $\binom {n/2}{2}$.

Hence, the total numbers of A.P. = $2 \cdot \binom {n/2}{2}$ = $$\frac {n \cdot (n-2)}{4}.$$

*Case 2*. When $n$ is odd.

No. of ways of selecting two even numbers = $\binom {n-1/2}{2}$.

And no. of ways of selecting two odd numbers = $\binom {n+1/2}{2}$.

**Hence , The total numbers of A.p = $\binom {n-1/2}{2}$ + $\binom {n+1/2}{2}$ = $$\frac {(n-1)^2 }{4}.$$**